# Why are my Android logcat logs being lost on device boot up?

Tags: android, logcat, boot

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue on a users phone with my app.  Essentially the widgets are failing to update on start-up of the device.  This user is now sending me log files (captured via the excellent [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat)).  However on boot up I am only seeing two debug log statements in this users logs when I should be seeing 20-30 (as I do on my phone).  What is strange is that these two statements are in the middle of the various processes and code which do the updates so its definitely already executed some of my log statements.  Any ideas as to why some of these statements are missing?  There's a lot going on on this users phone and many processes are being killed by the OS.  Should I then assume that some of these logs are never being recorded?

Answer (score 3):

First the log in android it's a circular log, that means that if you have a lot of logging going out there you're older statements will be overwritten. Why don't you use a custom solution like microlog for android http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/

Comment: Thanks Flo.  Microlog looks really good.  Might give that a try, especially its log to file capabilities.

Comment: FYI: Microlog4Android uses the Log4j API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command `logcat | grep 'YOURTAG'`, for only showing your apps logs. It can be done through any Terminal Emulator, or using Android Debug Bridge (adb)

Comment: Thanks, though CatLog gives me those same capabilities.  The issue I face is that I'm trying to look at a users logs remotely and not everything is appearing.